# How/Where to add action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

Complete noob with Ruby on Rails here. Trying to work through [the tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)  Made it to section 5.7 "showing posts".

The instructions say:

> so let's add the show action before proceeding.

and provide this piece of code:

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

But they don't mention where(which file) this needs to get added to. I am basically stabbing in the dark trying to figure out where this is supposed to go. Can someone point me to the right file please?

Comment: you should add the action show as `def show` method into controller, then add `app/views/posts/show.html.erb` view file =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

```
post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
```

piece of output `rake routes`. In order the rule to work, you should add the action show as `def show` method into `Posts` controller, then add **app/views/posts/show.html.erb** view file (if you use *ERubies* template renderer).

Comment: Oh, so that is not actually code, but rather it is the output that I see if running `rake routes` after I make the required changes to controller. I understand now, thank you =)